# Assign callback in a correct way

Tags: ios, swift

I am confused between 2 methods to get `callback` in my one class from another class.

This is my scenario :

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
  var callBack:(()->())?
}
```

I want to use this `callback` in my controller class. I know these 2 ways :

**Method 1:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.callBack = {[weak self] () in
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
func callBackFunction() {
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.callBack = callBackFunction
    return cell
}
```

**In first method the reference is weak, is it the same for method 2 ? which one is a better approach ? Pleas add proper explanation too.**

Comment: Method 1 is proper

Comment: @vivekDas Thanks, can you explain ?

Comment: Depends on where `callBackFunction()` is defined and how `callBackContainerObj` is declared.

Comment: @OOPer In my case callback is in TableCell and function is in controller class.

Comment: It's not clear enough. `callBackFunction()` is an instance method of some TableViewCell class and `callBackContainerObj` is an instance property of a view controller which contains TableView?

Comment: @OOPer Please see updated question.

Comment: So, `callBackFunction()` is an instance method of the ViewController, not a global function, right?

Comment: @OOPer yes, correct.

Comment: Then Method1 is the only choice to avoid reference cycle. Do you want explanation?

Comment: @OOPer Thanks. and Ahmad's explanation is enough to know more I will refer those links too.

Comment: I see. Please post another question when you find difficulty to choose which in a specific situation. One more thing. It's `weak`, not `unowned`. Never use `unowned` unless you completely understand what the difference between `weak` and `unowned`.

Comment: @OOPer You mean depending on another situation 2nd method can be a better approach than the 1st ?

Comment: The word `better` can be opinion-based. But in some situations, Method 2 does not make reference cycle and can be another option you can choose. But unless you and all of your colleague (including future) understand in what condition Method 2 can be safe, completely, you should better avoid Method 2.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks for the useful tip. Will avoid both method 2 and unowned for time being and will choose 1st method for this scenariao. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before directly choosing one of the mentioned options, we should recognize what is the `[weak self]` part is. The `[weak self]` called closure *capture list*; What's the reason of it?! Well, keep in mind that closures in Swift are **reference types**, whenever you assign a function or a closure to a constant or a variable, you are actually setting that constant or variable to be a reference to the function or closure. Which means that at some point, if you misusing closures in your code, it could leads to *retains cycles*.

Citing from [The Swift Programming Language - Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html):

> If you assign a closure to a property of a class instance, and the
>   closure captures that instance by referring to the instance or its
>   members, you will create a strong reference cycle between the closure
>   and the instance. Swift uses *capture lists* to break these strong
>   reference cycles.

Which means that you have to follow the first approach if you are aiming to use `self` in the body of the closure. Using the weak item self in the capture list resolves (prevents) retains cycles, and that's why you would go with the first method.

For more about how it is done, I would highly recommend to check: Automatic Reference Counting, [Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID57) section.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear and precise explanation. Surely will refer links too.